# MongoDB C# LINQ serialization error

Tags: linq, mongodb

I have a class `AttributeValue` containing two string fields:

```
string DataType
string Category
```

My mongo query is as below:

```
var test19 = _repo.All().Where(p => p.Rule.Any(r => r.Target.AnyOf.Any(an => an.AllOf.Any(av =>  av.Match != null && policyFilters2.Contains(string.Concat(av.Match.AttributeValue.DataType, av.Match.AttributeValue.Category))))));
```

where policyFilters2 is `List<string>`

The above query gives me an error:

> "Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression:
>   String.Concat(av.Match.AttributeValue.DataType,
>   av.Match.AttributeValue.Category)."

I am not sure what needs to be done to resolve this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MongoDB can do a search on concatenated values like that. Try concatenating the two fields separately in a field and then try the query.

Comment: Junaid, u r right. Mongo C# driver is not able to convert the string concat on the class properties to equivalent Mongo queries. The other option is to have Bson attributes. But since these classes are in biz layer, I didn't want to decorate them with attributes. As a result, I am filtering the data partially and then filtering them further in memory.

Comment: @RashmiPandit if I have answered your question, then please upvote and mark as the answer. :-)

Comment: Concatenating will also not work unless the underlying data is stored in a concatenated format

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I had to search for both the fields using logical AND rather than concatenating